# KDE - Server Authentication - Plasma - server failed the authenticity check (i.scdn.co)

Tags: kde, plasma5

I am having some random problems with KDE plasma desktop on Debian 11.

I keep getting this pop-up:

```
Server Authentication -- Plasma
The server failed the authenticity check (i.scdn.co).
The issuer certificate of a locally looked up certificate could not be found
```

I cant click details, as when I do it CRASHES the entire KDE desktop. It will continue to pop up every few minutes.

If I click continue, and it asks me if I want to trust the server, I just click for this session only, and the error doesn't reappear until I start a new plasma session.

Journalctl logs from around the time for the pop-up:

```
Apr 22 13:01:50 host dbus-daemon[958]: [session uid=1000 pid=958] Activating service name='org.kde.ksystemstats' requested by ':1.115' (uid=1000 pid=10455 comm="/usr/bin/plasmashell ")
Apr 22 13:01:52 host dbus-daemon[958]: [session uid=1000 pid=958] Successfully activated service 'org.kde.ksystemstats'
Apr 22 13:01:53 host dbus-daemon[958]: [session uid=1000 pid=958] Activating service name='org.kde.KSplash' requested by ':1.115' (uid=1000 pid=10455 comm="/usr/bin/plasmashell ")
Apr 22 13:02:52 host org.kde.KSplash[10481]: org.kde.knotifications: WaitForName: Service was not registered within timeout
Apr 22 13:02:52 host dbus-daemon[958]: [session uid=1000 pid=958] Activated service 'org.kde.KSplash' failed: Process org.kde.KSplash exited with status 1
```

Whois results for i.scdn.co appear to be registered to spotify, I do have the spotify application (installed through their PPA repository).

I've been using spotify for a while on this system, I don't know why suddenly this is happening.

Anyone know whats going on?

UPDATE:

I have isolated the error pop-up to a specific action.
I have the spotify application pinned to the KDE taskbar.
If I only mouse over the icon, Plasma immediately creates the pop-up and any button will crash plasma.
Strangely, alt-tabbing and using Spotify does not create a crash.

Running plasmashell interactively in konsole gets me this output when I mouse over the spotify icon:

```
QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is Breeze::WidgetStateEngine(0x555dc06aad20), parent's thread is QThread(0x555dc054f140), current thread is QQuickPixmapReader(0x7f73fc0a9ae0)
QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is Breeze::WidgetStateEngine(0x555dc06b6f80), parent's thread is QThread(0x555dc054f140), current thread is QQuickPixmapReader(0x7f73fc0a9ae0)
QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is Breeze::WidgetStateEngine(0x555dc06b6f80), parent's thread is QThread(0x555dc054f140), current thread is QQuickPixmapReader(0x7f73fc0a9ae0)
QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is Breeze::WidgetStateEngine(0x555dc06aad20), parent's thread is QThread(0x555dc054f140), current thread is QQuickPixmapReader(0x7f73fc0a9ae0)
QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is Breeze::WidgetStateEngine(0x555dc06b6f80), parent's thread is QThread(0x555dc054f140), current thread is QQuickPixmapReader(0x7f73fc0a9ae0)
QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is Breeze::WidgetStateEngine(0x555dc06b6f80), parent's thread is QThread(0x555dc054f140), current thread is QQuickPixmapReader(0x7f73fc0a9ae0)
QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is Breeze::WidgetStateEngine(0x555dc06aad20), parent's thread is QThread(0x555dc054f140), current thread is QQuickPixmapReader(0x7f73fc0a9ae0)
QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is Breeze::WidgetStateEngine(0x555dc06b6f80), parent's thread is QThread(0x555dc054f140), current thread is QQuickPixmapReader(0x7f73fc0a9ae0)
QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is Breeze::WidgetStateEngine(0x555dc06b6f80), parent's thread is QThread(0x555dc054f140), current thread is QQuickPixmapReader(0x7f73fc0a9ae0)
QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is Breeze::WidgetStateEngine(0x555dc06aad20), parent's thread is QThread(0x555dc054f140), current thread is QQuickPixmapReader(0x7f73fc0a9ae0)
QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is Breeze::WidgetStateEngine(0x555dc06aad20), parent's thread is QThread(0x555dc054f140), current thread is QQuickPixmapReader(0x7f73fc0a9ae0)
QObject::installEventFilter(): Cannot filter events for objects in a different thread.
QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is Breeze::WidgetStateEngine(0x555dc06aad20), parent's thread is QThread(0x555dc054f140), current thread is QQuickPixmapReader(0x7f73fc0a9ae0)
QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is Breeze::WidgetStateEngine(0x555dc06aad20), parent's thread is QThread(0x555dc054f140), current thread is QQuickPixmapReader(0x7f73fc0a9ae0)
QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is Breeze::WidgetStateEngine(0x555dc06aad20), parent's thread is QThread(0x555dc054f140), current thread is QQuickPixmapReader(0x7f73fc0a9ae0)
QWidget::repaint: Recursive repaint detected
QWidget::repaint: Recursive repaint detected
QBackingStore::endPaint() called with active painter; did you forget to destroy it or call QPainter::end() on it?
```

Comment: Are you on Debian / Ubuntu OS? If so you could try to execute `sudo dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates`. I was able to select Mozilla's certificates (for example `mozilla/ISRG_Root_X1.crt`) which overrides Debian's ones.